# AngularJS html5mode and rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have followed all the github issues on HTML5Mode breaking Angular apps in 1.5. I am having the same problem but none of the fixes are working for me.

Im doing the following:

```
<base href="/">
```

and

```
get '/*path', :to => "menus#index"
```

and

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
 .when("/users/:u_id/restaurants/:r_id/menus/:m_id/edit", { templateUrl: "/assets/menus/edit.html", controller: "MenuSectionCtrl" })
 .when("/users/:u_id/restaurants/:r_id/menus/:m_id/sections/:sec_id/items", { templateUrl:   "/assets/menus/items.html", controller: "MenuItemCtrl" })
 .when("/users/:u_id/restaurants/:r_id/menus/:m_id/sections/:sec_id/items/:i_id/option_sections", { templateUrl: "/assets/menus/option_sections.html", controller: "MenuOptionSectionCtrl" })
 .when("/users/:u_id/restaurants/:r_id/menus/:m_id/sections/:sec_id/items/:i_id/option_sections/:op_sec_id/options", { templateUrl: "/assets/menus/options.html", controller:       "MenuOptionCtrl" })
});
```

I am lost as to what to do next. I have tried every combination of routes and base[href].

Anybody have any ideas?

Also, I have followed this tutorial too. http://omarriott.com/aux/angularjs-html5-routing-rails/

Answer (score 3):

Try this link
http://start.jcolemorrison.com/angularjs-rails-4-1-and-ui-router-tutorial/

If you have mount only single angularjs application then it is very straight forward. You need to make this entry in routes.rb

```
get '*path' => 'application#index'
```

And in your application.controller change the index method as below

```
def index
  render layout: 'application'
end
```

Comment: this works and is the simplest solution. Just make sure to put `get '*path' => 'application#index'` on the bottom of routes.rb. Else all other JSON api endpoints are overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

The following link helped me to use `rack-rewrite` get which seems to work for me. [Here](https://www.angularonrails.com/get-html5-pushstate-working-angular-rails/) is the link. Only the following code in `config.ru` would allow `/api` routes to rails:

```
# config.ru

# This file is used by Rack-based servers to start the application.

use Rack::Rewrite do
  rewrite %r{^(?!.*(api|\.)).*$}, '/index.html'
end

require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
run Rails.application
```

Answer (score -1):

I managed to get mine working with:

```
get '*path', to: redirect('/#/%{path}')
```

The template I bought was working without hash after the first load but if you refresh the page it does not work. I tried manually adding the hash like /#/page and the above routing does it automatically.